# Why is Apache2 not finding my WSGI app?

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-404, flask

In my previous question, I asked how to make mod_wsgi use a specific Python version. Following the answer from that question, I created a Python 3.9 virtual environment and made WSGI use it. However, now my Flask app is not running at all - I just get the 404 page configured for the rest of my site. I get no errors when restarting Apache2 and the Apache error log is empty when I visit the site. I think the error must be due to my virtual environment, as I have created previous test Flask apps before using the same config style.

My virtual environment is located in `path/to/my/app/venv/`.

`path/to/my/app/runner.wsgi`:

```
import sys

# Make something appear in error log if the WSGI is run at all
raise ValueError()

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_DIR)

from my_app import app as application
```

Part of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=www-data group=www-data threads=4 python-home=/path/to/my/app/venv/
WSGIScriptAlias /my-app/ path/to/my/app/runner.wsgi
```

`/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load`

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "/path/to/my/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py39.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "path/to/my/app/venv"
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. It was really stupid. Basically, I was writing `/var/www/my_app` instead of `/var/www/my-app` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf`. I fixed the paths, disabled the site, enabled the site, reloaded Apache and now it works. I'm curious as to why Apache doesn't at least give a warning if it can't access the WSGI file.

Answer (score 0):

- Which user is running Apache?
- Can that user actually access your WSGI application? Check this by running `ls -la` on the path and all its components, or by using `namei` (`namei /path/....`)
- Is SELinux in enforcing mode? If so, check audit logs. `audit2why` can be useful (you may have to install some packages).

Comment: Apache is being run by `root` (1 instance) and `www-data` (multiple instances). I believe they can access the directory (which is in `var/www`), as I tried some tests I found online and the whole directory has permissions `0777` anyway. I don't think I'm using SELinux because all of the SELinux commands are not found.